# Chef recipe hangs with INFO: channel_request: 0 keepalive@openssh.com true

Tags: chef-infra, ubuntu-14.04, google-compute-engine, chef-recipe

I'm having trouble getting a chef recipe to run on a virtual machine on Google Compute Engine, running Ubuntu 14.04/Trusty. The VM is running chef-client and Chef 12.2.1, and the instance is booted using `knife google`.

After executing the "directory" resource and creating a dir, it just seems to hang on the next step, which is executing a bash script.

The output in verbose mode is

```
INFO: channel_request: 0 keepalive@openssh.com true
DEBUG: queueing packet nr 21 type 100 len 28
DEBUG: sent 52 bytes
DEBUG: read 68 bytes
DEBUG: received packet nr 420 type 98 len 44
INFO: channel_request: 0 keepalive@openssh.com true
DEBUG: queueing packet nr 22 type 100 len 28
DEBUG: sent 52 bytes
DEBUG: read 68 bytes
DEBUG: received packet nr 421 type 98 len 44
INFO: channel_request: 0 keepalive@openssh.com true
DEBUG: queueing packet nr 23 type 100 len 28
DEBUG: sent 52 bytes
DEBUG: read 68 bytes
DEBUG: received packet nr 422 type 98 len 44
INFO: channel_request: 0 keepalive@openssh.com true
DEBUG: queueing packet nr 24 type 100 len 28
DEBUG: sent 52 bytes
```

and on and on. I did get it to complete once, and it output

```
Chef Client finished, 39/41 resources updated in 645.826155425 seconds
```

but most of the time I wait much longer than that (> 1 hour) and it never finishes.

This bash resource does take a couple of minutes to manually execute when I ssh into the instance, but it never hangs like this. Is there some type of configuration that I need to set, or anything else I can do to speed up the process?

**EDIT**

Here is the script:

```
bash 'install_ffmpeg' do
  user user
  group group
  cwd naclports_path
  code "NACL_ARCH=pnacl TOOLCHAIN=pnacl make ffmpeg"
end
```

Comment: Show the bash script. It may be waiting for some input from your side.

Comment: @DracoAter added. I don't think it is because it does not prompt for any input when run manually ssh'd

Comment: Hum... is it chef log or a knife ssh log ? (sounds more like the ssh keepalive than something done by chef) I'm not used to GCE but according the the code you'll have to add `knife[:log_level] :debug`in your knife.rb to set chef-client run at debug level (and not just knife with `-VV`) to see what happens in the VM.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Tensibai. From the serial port console, it looks like the process is getting killed by the machine due to lack of memory. No idea why this is consuming so much RAM, but I guess that's a different issue to explore

Comment: Not enough RAM to compile ?

Comment: I guess so, will try with a high memory instance type. Thanks!

Comment: @Tensibai yes it worked! thanks. took forever though, more than 1200 seconds